# HTTP status for request param conflict?

Tags: rest, http, http-status-codes

I have a very straight forward problem, yet it is hard to find a formal standard. I have a REST endpoint like this.

```
/hotels?country=someCountry&city=someCity
```

If someone going to call it like this

***hotels?country=usa&city=tokyo***

there will be a conflict in params that the client has provided. What is the appropriate status code for the response (Error Response)? I know it would be OK to send ***400 - Bad Request***. But I need a more concrete answer.

**Edit**

I understand this can be easily solved in `/{country}/{city}/hotels` manner. Here I need to address this question in more generic perspective.

Another Example

```
/transactions?startDate=someDate&endDate=someLaterDate
```

I try

***/transactions?startDate=2012-09-03&endDate=2001-08-04***

Comment: I think the start/end date is a different issue. That is an invalid request - it shows that the caller has likely made a mistake and a good API will play nicely and inform the caller of anything unexpected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would not even send an error response, but return  status code `200` and an empty list. There is nothing wrong with this request, there is just no match in the database for the given query, then just return `[]`.
This must then be handled appropiately in the client.

If that endpoint did not even exist (e.g. no route for `/hotels`), then `404` would be the correct response.

Comment: I agree with you. But here what I need is to find out a more client friendly way to indicate it.

Comment: An empty list is indeed very client friendly, because clients can safely iterate emtpy lists and are likely not to break with an empty list. This is a best practice in RESTful apps. You could also consider wrapping your data into a response that also contains the number of rows and pagination offsets. See the accepted answer in this
 [https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/199742/restful-api-design-what-should-i-return-if-there-are-no-rows] thread.

Answer (score 1):

I think I would put a bit of a different spin on it. Instead of this being a conflict, you can also look at it as "The city Tokyo does not exist in the US".

I think this is a better way to think about it. There's also a few cities that exist in countries you might not expect. (There's a Paris in Canada, and one in the US).

So if you just consider this a 'non-existent city' in a valid country, maybe it's just a 404.

Aside tip: You should use standard ISO 2-letter country codes. They're the most common way to abbreviate countries.

Comment: I understand your point. I agree with you that I can send a 404, once I specify this as "/{country}/{city}/hotels" which would be a better approach. Could you please take my question in more general perspective? What I mean is when this is happened for a request which has number of query params which cannot be specified as path params??